# Count number of observations with elements in the same order

Tags: r

I am trying to pre-process some data in order to build a Sunburst plot in R. In short, I need to count how many observations have their elements in the same order.

The elements of each observation are character strings. The order does matter.

```
mylist <- list(c("a", "b", "c"),
               c("x", "y"), 
               c("b", "c", "a"),
               c("a", "b", "c"))
```

Desired output would be something like:

"a-b-c" = 2

"x-y" = 1

"b-c-a" = 1

Comment: something like `table(sapply(mylist, toString))`?

Comment: Yep, perfect!!!